# Notation suggestion for labeling of set

Tags: notation

Consider the two sets $L=\{a,b,c\}$ and $I=\{1,2,3\}$. There are six possible ways to pair up elements of the two sets:

1: $a\to1$, $b\to2$, $c\to3$

2: $a\to1$, $b\to3$, $c\to2$

3: $a\to2$, $b\to1$, $c\to3$

4: $a\to2$, $b\to3$, $c\to1$

5: $a\to3$, $b\to1$, $c\to2$

6: $a\to3$, $b\to2$, $c\to1$

**Question:** I want a compact way to refer to each of the 6 objects above that describes how the elements of $L$ are mapped to the elements of $I$. What is the proper (standard) notation to represent the labelings?

Comment: Do you know about the Symmetric group? It is the set of all bijections from a set to itself. Since you require there to be as many indices as elements, this could suffice. In your case you are working with $S_3$.

Answer (score 0):

What comes into mind is permutations. While this is not strictly permutations the same notation might be used. For example the first being $\begin{pmatrix}a & b & c \\ 1 & 2 & 3\end{pmatrix}$. Note however that the notation might be confused with a normal matrix (as it also can for permutations) so it would be wise to define the notation if used.